# SparkDataframe.load(),when I execute a load command where actually my data get stored?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

If I am loading one table from cassandra using spark dataframe.load().Where will my data gets loaded.Is it in spark memory.Or in datanode blocks ,if I am using yarn resource manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It will try to store in memory per number of partitions on the Worker Nodes / which in this context is a slightly better term than Data Nodes.
2. It will spill to disk if not enough memory on the Worker Nodes.
3. Per number of Cores / Executors, processing will occur. E.g. if you have, say, 20 Executors with 1 Core each, your concurrency of processing is 20 and spilling will occur via eviction. If you run out of disk, an error will result.

Worker Nodes is a better term here compared to Data Nodes, unless you have HDFS and processing locally, then Worker Node is equal to Data Node. Although you could argue what's in a name?

Of course, an Action will need to have been initiated.

And repartition and join or union latterly in the data pipeline affect things, but that goes without saying.